# Parse csv to decimal on different cultures using CsvHelper in c#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, decimal, csvhelper

Problem with parsing decimals by CsvHelper in c#.

I created a class that get csv file from byte[] istead of file, and it works correctly.

```
public static List<Topic> GetAll(byte[] attachmentBytes)
    {
        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(attachmentBytes))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), true))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                {
                    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
                    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                    csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                    return csv.GetRecords<Topic>().ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Like you can see I added class to map csv to object:

```
public class Topic
{
    [Name("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Name("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Name("DecimalPTS")]
    public decimal? DecimalPts { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how my example csv data looks like.

```
ID;description;DecimalPTS
1;singing;0,6
2;speaking;2,6
3;working;3,3
```

But this solution produces an error with

```
CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException : The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: '0,6'
    MemberType: System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

When I replaced just do Replace(',','.'); on input, localy test pass, but on my server test fails (seems like I have different culture localy, and on the server)

What I tried to fix this issue:

- I added `csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`
- I used `7.1.1` CSV Version, but changed to `12.1.2`, and still the same error

Unfortunately, nothing helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set your culture to `de-DE`

```
csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

You can do one more trick that, if your application works on

- local then you can set culture to `en-US` and if it's on a
- server then you can set culture to `de-DE`.

or vice versa.

**Demo:**

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"Path to your csv file");    
List<Topic> list = GetAll(bytes);

//Print list item to console
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {item.Id}\t Description: {item.Description}\t DecimalPTS: {item.DecimalPts}");
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Can you identify whether your app is working? means its on local or server in your program

Comment: This is the [issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/290) on github that you can get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

`var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo; culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";`

This looks working!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).