# CSVHelper Exponent with comma instead dot

Tags: c#, .net-core, csvhelper

I'm using CSVHelper and I don't know how to solve this.

Problem:
I'm trying to read a CSV with numbers like '3,23E+11' but I have this error:

```
The conversion cannot be performed.
Text: '3,27E+11'
MemberType: System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.NullableConverter'
```

I need to read it with comma values instead of dots.

I already tried change culture info

```cs
 public IEnumerable<DTO> ReadFile(Task<Stream> file)
        {
            IEnumerable<DTO> records;
            CultureInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("de-DE", false);
            nfi.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.Result))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, nfi))
                try
                {
                    csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (header, index) => header.Trim();
                    csv.Configuration.TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim;
                    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<decimal>().NumberStyle = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign;
                    csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = null;
                    csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
                    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CSVMapper>();
                    records = csv.GetRecords<DTO>().ToList();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            return records;
        }
```

I don't know if exists some way to parse the value in the cell using comma instead of dot :/

Thank you

Comment: Can you post a few lines of the CSV file?

Comment: Have you tried setting `csv.Configuration.CultureInfo` to a culture that uses comma as decimal separator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076433/parse-csv-to-decimal-on-different-cultures-using-csvhelper-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you share `CSVMapper`, `DTO` and an sample CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have setted the number configuration for `decimal`, but by your exception your property type is nullable (`decimal?`). Add the following line if you have any non-nullable `decimal` property, or replace the existing one if you only have the nullable version (`decimal?`) (notice the `?` in the code bellow)

```
csv.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<decimal?>().NumberStyle = 
    NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | 
    NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign;
```